# Laravel Illegal offset type in isset or empty Error when updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a project that i needed to change the primary keys on a table, so when i search how to make the $variable->save() method i encounter that i needed to add a

```
protected $primaryKey = ['cedula','nacionalidad'];
```

does are my primary keys on that table, but now when i make a

```
$variable->save()
```

I't returns a error

> ErrorException
>   Illegal offset type in isset or empty

here is my code where i update

```
$person = AVC::where(['nacionalidad'=>Auth::user()->nacionalidad , 'cedula' => Auth::user()->cedula ])->get();

    $person[0]->centro_votacion = Request('centro');

    $person[0]->save();

    dd($person[0]);
    return redirect()->back()->with('message','Se a agregado o Actualizado tu centro de Votacion');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use dd($person[0]); and return not null

try to use this

```
$person[0]->update();
```

ErrorException Illegal offset type in isset or empty appear because its not correctly formatted.